# Can a traditional nonconnected PAC spend money to support or oppose state ballot measures?

Tags: united-states, referendum

Assume a fully compliant FEC-registered nonconnected multicandidate PAC that already makes and reports direct contributions and also independent expenditures to influence the election of candidates in federal and state elections, using the single-fund as opposed to the allocation method.

We can't find any information on FEC website or anywhere else pertaining to regulations or reporting requirements for spending PAC money to support or oppose referendum ballot initiatives.

Is it permitted?
Are there limits?
How are these expenses reported to FEC?
Links?

We'll be looking at individual state-level requirements and reporting as well.